# How to change a 'Setting" in Visual Basic to Variant or Object Type?

Tags: vb.net, outlook, outlook-addin

I am trying to build a Addin for Outlook that allows a user to select a folder they want emails moved to when they hit a certain button. I am ussing a project setting called "EmailDestFolder" to define the folder after the user selects it, thats done as follows:

```
    Dim objOutlook As Object
    Dim objOlNamespace As Object

    objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    objOlNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").PickFolder

    If objOlNamespace.Name.Length >= 1 Then
        My.Settings.EmailDestFolder = objOlNamespace
    End If
```

Issue is this doesnt work when the setting type is set to "String" I tried changing the setting type to: "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder" but I get an error saying that settings cannot be an abstract type. Is there a way to change it to something like a Variant or Object type so I can set the folder.

Comment: There is no Variant in VB.NET and a generic `System.Object` cannot be serialized.

Comment: So pretty much nothing I can do to make that work then?

Comment: You could save the folder name which is what it looks like you are really after

Comment: Unfortunately, the folder name doesn't save the folder path. I actually had it save the name before but then I was limited to only folders that were one step under the inbox cause I had to tell the program which parent folder to look for the folder name in. If you got an idea of how to save the complete folder path that would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the MAPIFolder.EntryID property to a string variable. When you need to open that folder later, use Namespace.GetFolderFromID.